# Setting a value in structure fails

Tags: http, go, struct

I set the value in the structure, but it is not set. The methods are called consequently, not in parallel. How can that be? This is golang, forgot to say.

If I change the code to set value in the "start" method (instead of "init" method), it works; but setting value in "init" method fails. Looks very strange to me.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type tServer struct {
    ipAddress string
    port      string
    server    http.Server
}

var server tServer

func main() {
    server.ipAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    server.port = "12345"
    server.init()
    server.start()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}

func (srv tServer) init() {
    srv.server.Addr = srv.ipAddress + ":" + srv.port
    log.Println("srv.server.Addr=", srv.server.Addr) ////////////////////
}

func (srv tServer) start() {
    log.Println("srv.server.Addr=", srv.server.Addr) ////////////////////
    go srv.startServerRoutine()
}

func (srv tServer) startServerRoutine() {
    log.Println("Server started at", srv.server.Addr) //
    err := srv.server.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Server Error:", err) //
        return
    }
}
```

Here is the console:

```
2017/04/18 19:43:07 srv.server.Addr= 0.0.0.0:12345
2017/04/18 19:43:07 srv.server.Addr= 
2017/04/18 19:43:07 Server started at 
2017/04/18 19:43:07 Server Error: listen tcp :80: bind: permission denied
```

Comment: If you want a method to modify the value of its receiver you need to define that method on the pointer of that receiver https://tour.golang.org/methods/4

Comment: o.m.g., thank you. i knew that but i always forget it somehow. XD the same thing about zero being the first index in array. i always want to write loop starting at 1 instead of 0 XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to prototype of methods:

```
func (srv tServer) init()
    // ^^^ copies values
```

so:

```
server.init()   // updates its own copy of server, 
                // copy gets disposed after init() returns

server.start()  // uses its own copy of server
```

You need to pass `srv` by pointer to methods:

```
func (srv *tServer) init()
```

in that case both `init()` and `start()` calls will work on the same copy of `tServer` structure and will share values in its fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for [http.Server](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) you will see that a blank value is possible, and means ":http":

```
type Server struct {
       Addr      string      // TCP address to listen on, ":http" if empty
```

You set `srv.server.Addr` directly in `init()`, but this is not the proper way to use the `http.Server` type.

Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
func (srv tServer) startServerRoutine() {
    log.Println("Server started at", srv.ipAddress + ":" + srv.port) //
    err := srv.server.ListenAndServe(srv.ipAddress + ":" + srv.port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Server Error:", err) //
        return
    }
}
```